# Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory - Fixed Error in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, async.js

We have a collection in which stores 100 000 documents in a collection. I have to fetch all data and then update it (by adding one key).

Here is code

```
 checkinLib.getCheckinModel().find({},function(error, result){
        if(error){
            console.log('error', error);
        }
        else{
            console.log("length", result.length)
            async.forEachSeries(result, function(data, cb){
                console.log("data1", data)
                if(data.checkinData.time){
                    var dt = data.checkinData.time.toString();
                    var month = new Date(dt).getMonth();
                    var ss = parseInt(month);
                    var format = new Date(dt).getFullYear() + '-' + (ss+1) + '-' + new Date(dt).getDate();
                    checkinLib.getCheckinModel().update({'_id': data._id}, {'$set':{'checkinData.dateFormat': format}}, (err, update)=>{
                        if(err){
                            console.log('err', err);
                        }
                        else{
                            cb()
                        }
                    })
                }
            },function(error, result){
                console.log("finally error", error);
                console.log("finally data", result);
            })
        }
    })
```

It takes too much time to fetch. When I checked console on terminal then it returns

```
  <--- Last few GCs --->

  [3921:0x2c54c40]   166610 ms: Mark-sweep 1403.1 (1463.4) -> 1403.1 
  (1463.4) MB, 2717.4 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure GC in old space 
   requested
  [3921:0x2c54c40]   169350 ms: Mark-sweep 1403.1 (1463.4) -> 1403.0 
  (1438.4) MB, 2739.6 / 0.0 ms  last resort 
   [3921:0x2c54c40]   172066 ms: Mark-sweep 1403.0 (1438.4) -> 1403.0 
 (1437.9) MB, 2715.7 / 0.0 ms  last resort 


<--- JS stacktrace --->

   ==== JS stack trace =========================================

  Security context: 0xd093db9cef1 <JSObject>
   1: pre [/home/rahul/Documents/bluedolphinapi/node_modules/hooks-
  fixed/hooks.js:~116] [pc=0x19b16ba1a964](this=0x3e51244ca7e9 <model 
 map = 0x39723645c251>,name=0x15ea23ee34d1 <String[16]: 
 $__original_save>,isAsync=0xd093db822f1 <false>,fn=0x113b342daf9 
<JSFunction fn (sfi = 0xd83c50733d1)>,errorCb=0xd093db82241 
 <undefined>)
2: arguments adaptor frame: 3->4
4: /* anonymous */ [/home/rah...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap 
out of memory
1: node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
2: 0x13740dc [/usr/local/bin/node]
3: v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(char const*, bool) [ 
/usr/local/bin/node]
4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) 
[/usr/local/bin/node]
5: v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, 
v8::internal::AllocationSpace) [/usr/local/bin/node]
6: v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInTargetSpace(int, 
v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
7: 0x19b16b8840dd
```

I have run this command

```
node --max-old-space-size=4096 fileName.js
```

nothing happens,My system have got hang and no one data updated.

Node version is v8.4.0

Npm version is 5.3.0

I have many search and tried but still not working and Is there any method or query in which able to update all documents?

Comment: does your code even get to `console.log("length", result.length)` at all?

Comment: `1 lakh data` ... so, that's "100,000 data" ... bytes? kilobytes? megabytes? gigabytes? "100,000" by itself is just a number and adds no meaning to your question

Comment: Start by properly calling the callback `cb` _at all times_.

Comment: @ jaromanda console.log("length", result.length). this statement not be printed

Comment: `format = new Date(dt).getFullYear() + '-' + (ss+1) + '-' + new Date(dt).getDate()` lets hope this process never runs over midnight on the last day of a month

Comment: @RahulSaini - ok, so `checkinLib.getCheckinModel().find` fails - so the rest of the code is actually irrelevant to the problem :p - can you explain what you mean by "100,000 data" ..

Comment: Thers are  approx 1 lakh documents  in a collection

Comment: ahhh ... and how big on average is each document?

Comment: I would recommend you look at using mongodb [stream/cursor](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/tutorials/streams/)

Comment: or maybe [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33594397/how-to-update-a-large-number-of-documents-in-mongodb-most-effeciently)

Comment: average of each document size is 500 bytes